# IOS - Custom Input View to text view

Tags: ios, textview

I have created a custom view of size 1024 by 300. I gave clear color to its background and set it as inputView to textView.

```
view_datePicker = [[DatePickerView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 356)];
    view_datePicker.delegate = self;
    view_datePicker.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.txtView_scheduleDate.inputView = view_datePicker;
```

It is working fine but its background color remain gray.

Here is a screen shot.
[image]

Can I make background color of input view to clearColor?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

use  [self.txtView_scheduleDate.inputView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

Comment: Is DatePickerView is custom class ??

Comment: check .m implementation of this class.and chnage BackgroundColor

Comment: No. Not working. I think IOS dont allow color. It has default color which cannot be changed.

Comment: Are you using UIDatePicker? or you can also search for custom uidtaepicker and change its background color